# Django REST framework checks unnecessary permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Am I using django rest framework (v3.4.6) object level permissions. However, I cannot figure out a few things. First I created a custom permission that checks if user works for a specific shop:

```
class Works4Shop(BasePermission):
  def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

    profile = request.user.profile
    if obj.shop in profile.shops.all():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I then added `permission_classes = (Works4Shop,)` to a new custom view class `ShopItemsView(APIView)`
Now starts the curious part first I read that I need to explicitly check for object level permissions by calling `self.check_object_permissions(request,obj)`. However what I see is that getting any object through model manager enforces the policy on retrieved objects. Well not exactly, it does call the `has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)` but it ignores the result. The issue is the performance, this kind of thing creates to many unnecessary selects to DB. Can anyone explain this? I can also post logs from the DB.

Comment: Apart from your question. Can you explain why you are using both `profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)` and     `profile = request.user.profile`  for assigning profile ? I don't see the need for both

Comment: My understanding is that object level permissions are designed to check if every single returned object satisfies this permission condition. Maybe you want just a regular `has_permission()`, which is checked once per request?

Comment: @rrmerugu That was a mistake on my part during copying of the code. I was trying different methods to get the profile.

Comment: @serg Yes. However, the documentation states the the explicit call to the `self.check_object_permissions(request,obj)` is needed and also whats the point of the checks if they return `False`  but the backend dismisses their results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was more simple than I thought. Basically this problem only occurs when using the browsable API. During rendering of the template there are many template tags for forms that use each kind of request specified in the View class (post,put,delete, etc.) and the object permissions is checked for each form individually. When I used pure json format everything started to work as it should, no unnecessary checks etc.

There is however one issue. The browsable api checks permissions for every object fetched which in turn creates an issue: you don't know what is the class of obj in `has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)` so you should make an explicit check or the APIView will throw a `TypeError`